# I randomly lost coins in Overwatch?

Tags: overwatch

I went into my hero gallery to look at Genji's stuff but when I selected him my coins fell to 2800 from 3800. Does anyone know why this happened? I don't know if this helps but I play on Xbox One.

Comment: Why don't you take a screenshot of your all heroes page so we can see what unlocks you have? Have you checked every single hero to see which skin may have been bought?

Answer (score 1):

You must have accidentally purchased something without realizing it. If that's the case then there's nothing anyone here can do, but you should definitely contact their customer support.

Comment: Like I said in the comment above I saw the coins go down when I selected Genji. And I went through my skins I didn't see anything new.

Comment: @Robbie just contact customer support, there is nothing else we can do

Comment: On PC, clicking "Equip" pops up a confirmation dialog to complete the purchase (even for the smallest purchase of 25 coins). Does it do the same on Xbox? That would rule out accidental purchases.

Comment: Yeah it does give a pop up confirmation.

Answer (score -2):

This is a fairly common glitch in 2 ways.

1. If you commonly switch between devices a bit, or you have played on the PTR, when switching back to another device, you may lose coins or XP or other currencies. I don’t know why this happens. To be honest it is Blizzards fault.
2. This can happen if you have tonnes of coins and you have used about 1 thousand of it, the currencies can glitch out and you may end up paying less, or more than what you bought it for.

I know this answer is late, but I hope it helps.

Comment: Xbox doesn't have PTR and I only had 3800 coins.